# getting output from a file using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have a file which consists of data, am trying to get particular output from the file. When i am using the "return" [using return for segregating the output further ] statement in loop it is printing only first line of the output.

I have defined all the variables correctly:

```
def show_command(filename, startline, endline):
      with open(filename) as input_data:
            for line in input_data:
                  if line.strip() == startline:
                       break
            for line in input_data:
                  if line.strip() == endline:
                       break
                  output = line
                  return output
  show_command(filename, startline, endline)
```

#

it is printing only first line of the total output.

Current Boot Variables:

### Actual output is

Current Boot Variables:

sup-1
NXOS variable = bootflash:/nxos.7.0.3.I4.6.bin
No module boot variable set

Boot Variables on next reload:

sup-1
NXOS variable = bootflash:/nxos.7.0.3.I4.6.bin
No module boot variable set

#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're returning only that captured line, you need to collect all the lines instead before returning them, for example:

```
def show_command(filename, startline, endline):
    with open(filename, "r") as input_data:
        output = None  # hold our contents
        for line in input_data:
            if line.strip() == startline:
                output = ""  # start collecting lines
            elif line.strip() == endline:  # end of our area of interest
                break  # end the loop
            elif output is not None:  # if we started collecting lines...
                output += line  # collect the current line
        return output  # return the collected lines
```

Or if you want to do it with your approach:

```
def show_command(filename, startline, endline):
    with open(filename, "r") as input_data:
        for line in input_data:
            if line.strip() == startline:
                break
        output = ""
        for line in input_data:
            if line.strip() == endline:
                break
            output += line
        return output
```

Comment: Thank yo u very much zwer